# request matching with RewriteRule returns permission denied

Tags: apache-httpd

I am experiencing a bizarre apache error. I'd like to rewrite all requests from `/api/media/fi/le/path.jpg` to `/media/fi/le/path.jpg`

This are rewrite rules setup in virtual host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /api/v1/* /src/api/v1/index.php [L]
RewriteRule /api/media/(.*) /media/$1 [L]
```

If I point the browser to `/media/fi/le/path.jpg`, the image gets server successfully. If I go to `/api/media/fi/le/path.jpg` it complains that I do not have permission to access the resource. I must have permission, because I can access the file if no rewrites are done. How should I rewrite the last RewriteRule so that it would serve the images?

I added logging directive `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` to see what the apache is doing under the covers. This are the results:

```
 init rewrite engine with requested uri /api/media/32/ee/0e60731bcb220c7c7b.jpg
 applying pattern '/api/v1/*' to uri '/api/media/32/ee/0e60731bcb220c7c7b.jpg'
 applying pattern '/api/media/(.*)' to uri '/api/media/32/ee/0e60731bcb220c7c7b.jpg'
 rewrite '/api/media/32/ee/0e60731bcb220c7c7b.jpg' -> '/media/32/ee/0e60731bcb220c7c7b.jpg'
 local path result: /media/32/ee/0e60731bcb220c7c7b.jpg
 go-ahead with /media/32/ee/0e60731bcb220c7c7b.jpg [OK]
```

I can visit the url `mydomain.com/media/32/ee/0e60731bcb220c7c7b.jpg` manually and the image gets server with no problem. What am I missing?

Complete .conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /home/user/project/src
        ServerName project.com
        ErrorLog logs/project-error_log
        CustomLog logs/project-access_log common
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <Directory /home/user/project/src>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule /api/v1/* /api/v1/index.php
        RewriteRule /api/media/(.*) /media/$1 [L]

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/project.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/project.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/project.com/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is weird behaviour with rewrite engine.

```
RewriteRule /api/media/(.*) /media/$1 [L]
```

Will always return forbidden. After `mv media images` and changing the above directive to `RewriteRule /api/media/(.*) /images/$1 [L]`, permission error is gone.